# Error during harmonisation in TwoSampleMR (R-package)

Tags: r

I am trying to perform Mandalian Randomisation using the R package “TwoSampleMR”.
As exposure data, I use instruments from the GWAS catalog. (Phenotype - Sphingolipid levels).
As a outcome data, I use GISCOME ischemic stroke outcome GWAS (http://www.kp4cd.org/index.php/node/391)
I have an error when I do harmonization by the command harmonise_data().
The text of the error is:
**Error in data.frame(…, check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0**.
I have noticed that the error is caused by some exact lines in the file with outcomes. When I make a text file that contains only one line from the original file and use it as outcome data, some lines cause an error, and someones don’t.
As an example this one causes an error:

MarkerName CHR POS Allele1 Allele2 Freq1 Effect StdErr P-value
rs10938494 4 47563448 a g 0.2139 0.0294 0.0519 0.5706

This one doesn’t:

rs1000778 11 61655305 a g 0.2559 0.0939 0.0493 0.05705

Here is all commands that I use.

```
library(TwoSampleMR)
library(MRInstruments)
data(gwas_catalog)
exp <- subset(gwas_catalog, grepl("Sphingolipid levels", Phenotype))
exp_dat<-format_data(exp)
exp_dat<-clump_data(exp_dat)
exp_dat
out_dat<-read_outcome_data(
 snps=exp_dat$SNP,
 filename='giscome.012vs3456.age-gender-5PC.meta1.txt'
 sep='\t', snp_col='MarkerName',
 beta_col='Effect',
 se_col='StdErr',
 effect_allele_col='Allele1',
 other_allele_col='Allele2',
 eaf_col='Freq1',
 pval_col='Р-value'
)
dat<-harmonise_data(exporsure_dat=exp_dat, outcome_dat=out_dat)
```

What would be the reason for this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Is `giscome.012vs3456.age-gender-5PC.meta1.txt` your input file here?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded it to my computer and use as  local GWAS summary data.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to comment without looking at your sample input file but you might encounter this sort of error when there are inconsistencies with naming the exposure columns in your data frame.
Please see this thread on.

https://github.com/MRCIEU/TwoSampleMR/issues/226